# Create subnet with address_prefixes error

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I used below code to create subnet but the field address_prefixes shows following error. Please guide.

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "datbrick_subnet" {
 count                   = length(var.subnet_address)
 name                    = element(var.subnet_name, count.index) 
 address_prefixes          =  element(var.subnet_address, count.index)
 resource_group_name      = var.subscriptionrg_name
 virtual_network_name     = var.vnet_name
 }
  variable "subnet_address" {
  default = ["10.0.0.0/26", "10.0.1.0/26"]
  }
```

count.index is 1
| var.subnet_address is tuple with 2 elements. Inappropriate value for attribute "address_prefixes": list of string required.

Comment: What is the structure of var.subnet_address?

Comment: I have attached the variable i used in the code. However if i use address_prefix then terraform runs with a warning only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `address_prefixes` should be **list**. Please try the following:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "datbrick_subnet" {
 count                   = length(var.subnet_address)
 name                    = element(var.subnet_name, count.index) 
 address_prefixes        = [element(var.subnet_address, count.index)]
 resource_group_name     = var.subscriptionrg_name
 virtual_network_name    = var.vnet_name
 }
```